# How do you continue a for loop with a keyboard input in python?

Tags: python, linux, io

I have a for loop that uses `subprocess.call()` to call a linux program. Sometimes it takes too long, and I would like to be able to skip to `continue` the loop. Is there a way I could watch for a keyboard input (say `s`), while the `subprocess.call()` is running?

```
for x in y:
    if lookforkeyboardinput = s:
        continue
    subprocess.call(['program', x])
```

Something like this.

Answer (score 2):

using a keyboard interrupt exception:

```
for x in y:
    try:
        subprocess.call(['program', x])
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        continue
```

example:

```
from time import sleep

for x in range(0, 5):
    try:
        sleep(5)
        print x
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        continue
```

output:

```
hedde-mpb:Desktop hedde$ python test.py 
1 
^C  // pressed right after 1 appears, slightly over 5 seconds later 3 appears
3
```

Comment: This would cause the program to be unexitable via ctrl+c. How do I set the key to be `s` instead?